# What jobs should an "Excel Guru" look for?

Tags: job-search, skills, title

I'd like to get a job working with Excel and, if possible, VBA macros.

When I search job boards, what jobs should I look for? Currently I look for anything with "Excel" in the title (which seems uncommon), or in the job description (which is too broad).  My last job title was "Data Analyst", but most jobs of that title seem to involve much more than what I did.

Comment: Look for MS Office.  It would be unlikely you'd be working just in Excel.  Also, this question is likely off-topic as we can't really help you identify search terms to find suitable jobs.

Comment: Look for VBA developer jobs on Wall Street.

Comment: Just know that there are a ton of upper level and PM jobs in corporate America that use Excel - too much.  I create apps that do reporting yet everyone still wants full control so that they can prove worth in completing a document.  If you can't get one of these jobs you need to focus more on analytics or VBA.

Comment: First of all do not use word "_Excel_", ever. Using word "Excel" is just as wrong and not professional as using word "Xerox" instead of "printer" or "copier".

The correct term is _spreadsheet_ software. 

Notable spreadsheet software are [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/), [Calligra Sheets](https://www.calligra.org/sheets/), [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org) and possibly others. Unlike mentioned [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), MS Excel is a _proprietary_ software which makes it unethical.

Comment: Onlyjob: I've considered doing that, but I'm an expert with Excel, know little about LibreOffice, and have never heard of the others. Why is focusing on Excel that unethical?  (By the way, I also used to repair copiers for Xerox. That was the only brand I knew how to fix).

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson If you build programs in Excel VBA (aka plugins/macros), then those programs will only work with Microsoft Excel (and probably only work with the same version which you tested on). I don't see an ethical problem with this if your customers are aware of the dependency.

Comment: "My last job title was "Data Analyst", but most jobs of that title seem to involve much more than what I did." - This is a good thing. You want to advertise yourself as being able to do more than before, not less. Look for "VBA/Excel/Office/Office plugin Developer".

Comment: Hello Shawn, Excel is a great tool for many things.  I used to use it a lot (as a mechanical engineer) but got fed up with new versions breaking my VBA macros.  Now I only use it for simpler things.  I branched out into other programming languages, especially c++.  I think that you should focus on expanding your skills in data analysis.  Then you could list Excel as one of your proficiencies.  If I were interviewing you and you focused on Excel then I would view you in the same light as a carpenter who was way too proud of his tape measure skills.

Comment: Expertise in a tool is fragile -- things change and become obsolete; also, you run into the when-all-you-have-is-a-hammer-everything-looks-like-a-nail problem. Focus on what you were doing with Excel instead, both in your job search and in your continued learning. Learn more about statistics and data analysis, learn programming in languages other than VBA, Find a job where, while you will be using Excel, you can learn more about what you are using the tool for, and other tools that you can use to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of Job Title Suggestions that Use Excel**

Administrative Assistant, Department Assistant, any kind of 'analyst' role (research analyst, etc), job titles with 'research' in them (research assistant) might be appropriate, but you'd have to read the job description, look into positions in accounting (you generally need a 4-year degree to be an accountant, but often there are assistants and administrators in an accounting department), positions with the word 'business' or 'financial' and one of the other words might be appropriate (again, read job description).

**Disclaimer**

If your only experience was just doing work in excel with very little input or intention on your part, it will be difficult to convince someone of your qualifications. Positions that are administrative in nature will generally require good communication skills. Positions that are industry specific they will generally want you to have similar industry experience (financial, healthcare).